# Arangin Iframes in a matrix layout

Tags: html, iframe, dashboard

I have multiple interactive HTML tables which I want to arrange in matrix layout- similar to how they are arranged in some analytical platforms - for example Bloomberg. I have included a couple of links to the desired layout showing multiple small tables:

[image]

[image]

Do you think I can arrange a few frames in a similar fashion?

Can you please help me with 4 iframes each 300*300 pixes in size in square layout?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you looking for CSS help? HTML help? Additionally: what have you tried?

Comment: Can anyone comment on this please?

Comment: I am wondering if I iframes are secondary - I need a static html grid - is there a way to draw it in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for? It puts 4 iframes inside of a 2x2 table. There are certainly other ways to do it via css (using floated elements, or inline-block elements - or even flexbox), but this is the basic, pure HTML way to do it.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe></td>
        <td><iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe></td>
        <td><iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Tyzoid - is there any software which allows to draw fixed layout like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want this to be a web panel, then most will write it manually like so. You *could* use a server-side language like PHP, but unless you need it, why bother?